# What is the best way to include line break as part of maxlength in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, line-breaks

It seems like line break isn't being counted as part of the maxlength set in a textarea causing errors when posting to database. I tried to add validation like this, but it fails to capture when user copy paste values in the textarea. Can anyone please advise?

```
$("textarea.objective").on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
        var x = $(this).val()
        var newLines = x.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g);
        var addition = 0;
        if (newLines != null) {
            addition = newLines.length;
        }
        var maxLength = parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength")) ;
        if (maxLength <= $(this).val().length + addition
                 && e.keyCode !== 46 
                    && e.keyCode !== 8) {
             e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ffe8f3');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add **onChange** hook to solve it. like this: `$("textarea.objective").on("keydown keyup change", function(e) {
`

Comment: Instead of using `key` events, try using `$(...).on('input;, function(){ ... })`

Comment: `this.value.length` includes line breaks for me. It's a bug in jQuery, [*see the docs*](https://api.jquery.com/val/): "*Note: At present, using .val() on <textarea> elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value. When this value is sent to the server via XHR, however, carriage returns are preserved (or added by browsers which do not include them in the raw value). A workaround for this issue can be achieved using a valHook as follows:*"